# Storing manual test cases in GitHub

Tags: testcase

I saw in another [post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12448/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-a-github-repo-to-track-test-cases) about tracking test cases in Github.

Where can I write manual test cases in Github? I do not see any options. I am putting my automated test cases in Github but I also want to put manual for some of the ones which we cannot automate.

Comment: Cant you simply commit text or Excel file with description of manual tests to Git?

Comment: The last time I looked, Git will let you commit pretty much anything. You just need to create some form of file containing your test cases and then commit them - I would suggest you decide on some kind of naming or organization standard, though, or you will eventually have so many test cases you won't be able to find anything.